# How to restart Hangfire server, or stop it and start a new one, to change the Queues it's processing?

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire, asp.net-core-5.0

In my asp.net 5 app I'm using Hangfire to process only certain Queues, based on which tenants the server should be looking after. So at app startup I look up which Queues and start the Hangfire server accordingly.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ... do stuff

        services.AddHangfire(config => config
                                .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
                                .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                                .UseSqlServerStorage(hangfireConnectionString, new SqlServerStorageOptions
                                {
                                    QueuePollInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500)
                                })
        );

        string[] queueNames = GetQueueNamesForThisServerToProcess();

        services.AddHangfireServer(options =>
        {
            options.Queues = queueNames;
        });

        // ... do more stuff
    }
```

Sometime later I want to change the Queues that this server is processing. I *think* I need to just stop this hangfire server and start another one ... but a) how do I get a reference to this one, and b) how should I correctly start a new one, given that the advised method to start a Hangfire server in aspnet core is using `services.AddHangfireServer()`?

Comment: This https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-queues.html could help you.

Comment: Thanks @u1986237, I've read already that but didn't find anything relevant. Was there something specific you saw there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## stop a running server

BackgroundProcessingServer can be accessed in any controller after been injected

```
_server.SendStop();
await _server.WaitForShutdownAsync(new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
_server.Dispose();
```

## start a new server

AddHangfireServer can be triggered accessing an injected IApplicationBuilder

```
  _applicationBuilder.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions
  {
    WorkerCount = 1,
    Queues = new[] { "customqueuename" },
    ServerName = "Custom server 2",
  });
```

## startup.cs

```
  services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundProcessingServer, BackgroundProcessingServer>();
  services.AddSingleton<IApplicationBuilder, ApplicationBuilder>();
```

Look [here for a complete POC](https://github.com/stesee/HangfireHelloWorld/blob/main/Controllers/PlaygroundController.cs#L91).

Use `JobStorage.Current.GetConnection().RemoveTimedOutServers(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15));` to update /hangfire/servers

Comment: Thanks @stefan.seeland! I'll try it out when back from vacation but it seemed useful so I awarded the bounty :)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, the poc is .net5 based -https://github.com/stesee/HangfireHelloWorld/blob/main/WebApplicationHangfire.csproj .

Comment: I'm not sure either... I'll assemble my thoughts better and rewrite :)

Comment: Sorry, clearly it's .net5. I'm just confused with some things: 1) in Startup I call `services.AddHangfireServer()` which creates an IHostedService of type `BackgroundJobServerHostedService`. But in the POC what happens to that? Controller gets a IBackgroundProcessingServer but is that the same one as the BackgroundJobServerHostedService's `_processingServer`? 2) isn't it weird to use `IApplicationBuilder` outside the startup process? e.g. when does that builder get built if not in `Main()`? 3) Calling `UseHangfireServer()` does slightly different things to `AddHangfireServer()`, is that ok?

Comment: Can this be done without code, for example making some kind of API call?

Comment: In the current version of Hangfire, the `IApplicationBuilder.UseHangfireServer()` method is deprecated in favor of `IServiceCollection.AddHangfireServer()` however we can't alter the services after startup.